# Probability of generating a sequence of numbers between 1 and n

Tags: probability, statistics, random, random-functions

Let's say we want to generate a random number between 1 and n, n-times,then the probability that every integer between 1 and n appears once in the generated sequence of random numbers is $\frac{n!}{n^n}$. So if we were to generate a number between 1 and 10, 10-times, the probability that every number between 1 and 10 appears once in the generated sequence of numbers is $\frac{10!}{10^{10} }$, which is about 1 in 3000. So we should expect that if we do this process of generating 10 numbers 3000 times we should get a sequence of numbers where all numbers between 1 and 10 apeear once only one time. But when I tried this on my calculator(it has a button for generating integers) I got that pattern of all integers between 1 and 10 appearing without repeating after my 15th trial! So does that mean my calculator dose not actually generate random numbes?

Or in another words: what is the probability that after generating 10 numbers (between 1and 10) randomly 15 times you get a sequence where all integers between 1 and 10 appear once without repeating?

Comment: In your last question do you mean "exactly once" or "at least once"?

Comment: I guess, at least once is what I really mean.

Comment: Either you're not really simulating this problem correctly on your calculator or the "random number generator" in your calculator has an incredibly short period before it repeats. // Even the very best RNG's repeat eventually but with a really huge period.// The default generator in R is the Mersenne-twister, which has period $2^{19937} - 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that after generating 10 numbers (between 1 and 10) randomly 15 times you get a sequence where all integers between 1 and 10 appear **at least** once is

$$
1-\left(1-\frac{10!}{10^{10}}\right)^{15}\approx0.00543.
$$

Comment: I did a similar calculation and got the same answer: $15*(10!/10^{10} )$

Comment: @I0_0I Your calculation is correct for the "exactly once" case. Of course both numbers are extremely close  (since the probability of two or more occurrences of the sequence in question is extremely low).

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing:

> Probability of seeing 10 distinct numbers is about 1 in 3000. So we should expect that if we do this process 3000 times we should get the outcome only one time.

This is not true. By your logic, since a coin flip has a $1/2$ chance of being heads, if you flip a coin twice, you should always get exactly one heads and one tails, which is not true.

In your situation, it is entirely possible (but extremely unlikely) that you get a sequence of 10 distinct numbers *every single time out of the 3000 trials*.

The interpretation of "the probability is about 1 in 3000" should be this: if you did this process $n$ times and computed the proportion of trials where you did see  10 distinct numbers, then this proportion will approach $1/3000$ as $n \to \infty$. (This is the law of large numbers.)

For a fixed large $n$, it will usually be close to $1/3000$, but it is still possible that it is not; things like the central limit theorem can quantify this more concretely.